# Set DocumentRoot/Directory in httpd.conf to the current home directory

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

We are using an AFP server in our network to synchronize all home directories on all mac's in the office. This is working just fine, only not when an user is moving to another mac and wants to reach for it's "htdocs" files (this directory won't sync because it's not in the home directory).

I found out that there is a possibility to change the location of the localhost root directory. To change the root directory you've to modify the **DocumentRoot** and **Directory** path inside the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` file. Unfortunately it's not possible to use a path similar to `~/` this will give the following error, when restarting Apache:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 229 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot must be a directory
```

Is it possible to use for example `~/www` so all user that login on the mac will have there own xampp directory. I also wonder if it's possible to make an alias to escape the error?

Comment: The reason why the tilde (`~`) cannot be used / resolved there is because it does not make sense for a system daemon. _Which_ users home directory should the http server publish? MacOS is, like all unixoid systems, a multi user system after all.

Comment: You might want to try apaches mod_userdir to publish each users content via a single apache http server. That way all users can access "their" stuff as `http://<domain name>/~<username>... note the tilde again in this which this time _does_ make sense, since followed by a user name.

Comment: @arkascha using `localhost/~username` sounds not like the best solution, personally I think using `/Users` as root is a better way to approach this.

Comment: You can rewrite it however you like. The point is: you have a multi user environment and you have to consider that.

Comment: @arkascha Okay, but if I set it to `/Users/my_acc/www` than it works fine, but only for my account. I want it to work for every account (what is not static).

Comment: That is impossible. How should the server know _which_ account?

Comment: Don't know that's why I'm asking, perhaps with an piece of code or plugin.

Comment: No. The problem is not about the _how_. It is a logical problem. You have 3 user accounts on a system. You request the system for "the users home folder". Which one should it deliver?

Comment: Ehm, the one currently active? Anyway you made your point I will make `/Users` the document root and at the root directory I'll add an index.php file which asks you to select which home folder you want to use. After submitting a session and a specific htaccess gets created.

Comment: The reply "the one currently active" suggests that you have not really understood how a multi user system works. And how a http server works. It simply does not know about which user is currently logged in. Actually there might be several users logged in at the same time. You should give that a little thought. It probably would be possible to hack something that allows apaches internal rewriting to react on a test if some user currently has a graphical login on the system or something and if that is unique. But that would be a horrible hack! Ugh! That is not what an http server is for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering to the answer on the question, ["Apache wildcard documentroot"](https://serverfault.com/questions/306439/).

Use VirtualDocumentRoot.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/%1/Sites
</VirtualHost>
```